# How to login and then submit another post with WWW::Mechanize in Perl

Tags: perl, post, www-mechanize

I have a PHP page (index.php) where, after the login with a form, I can send an SMS throughout another form.
Through WWW::Mechanize I was able to login (if I print the response it correctly shows the second form to send the SMS) but I am not able to submit the other form, if I print the response I get the submit SMS page instead of the SMS result page. Here's a code snippet, am I missing something?

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $to = 'xxxxxxx';
my $text = 'test';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( 'http://x.x.x.x/index.php' );

# Login

$mech->submit_form(
    fields      => {
        oper    => 'login',
        usr    => 'xxx',
        pwd    => 'xxx',
    }
);

# Now that I logged in I can send the SMS

#$mech->get( 'http://x.x.x.x/index.php' ); Guess this get is useless

$mech->submit_form(
    fields    => {
            to  => $to,
            text => $text,
            submit => 'Send Message'
    }
);
```

EDIT: Adding second form HTML code, it may be useful.

```
<form name="sendsms" method="post" action="index.php">
<p>Phone Number:<br><input type="text" size="30" name="to"></p>
<p>Message:<br><textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="text></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset"><br></form>
```

Comment: Is the second `get` after `submit` needed?

Comment: Tbh it was commented on my code but I forgot to remove the line, anyway it does not work either way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select form to submit. Try this:

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields    => {
            to  => $to,
            text => $text,
            submit => 'Send Message'
    }
    button => "your_submit_button_name_here",
);
```

Comment: There is only one form in the HTML code but I did try your solution as well, no luck though :(

Comment: I mean may be you need add `button => "your_button_name"` to your code?

Comment: Nope, it says "There is no form with the requested fields". I'll add the HTML code of the form now btw.

Answer (score 0):

try that :

```
$mech->form_name("sendsms");
$mech->field("to","$to");
$mech->field("text","$text"); 
$click();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you need to elaborate more. Why should OP "try that"?